# Why is wifi slow on desktop pc but fast on laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, network-adapter

I've tried reading other similar questions but none of the suggestions help.

I have a new desktop PC.  I bought around 5 months ago.

Windows 10, AMD Ryzen 9 3900, 16GB 3200MHz RAM, Intel Wi-Fi 6 (802.11ax)

This is located in my bedroom, approx 15 meters away from the router (in another room).  The internet has always been slow and constantly dropping.  I assumed it was the wifi card as it was a fairly cheap pre-built pc.

I recently replaced the wifi card with: [Ubit AX/AC WiFi 6 Card Dual Band 2974 Mbps AX200](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07Y82HZV1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

This was giving me speeds of around 16mb/s & was often dropping to around 0.8 - 2mbps.  I was constantly spending a good 15 minutes resetting the network adapter/restarting pc before I could use it.

The problem I have is that my laptop/phone etc all have great connections in this room.

I've just run a speed test on google.

Desktop: **0.8mbps** download speed.

Laptop: **67mbps**

In the exact same spot in the room.

**Things I have tried.**

1. Replacing the wireless card.
2. Repositioning the pc
3. Restarting the router.
4. Removing the device driver and re-installing them.  (I have the latest ones).
5. Preventing Windows from turning off the device to save power (in device manager)

If anyone has any ideas what could be causing the problem, I will be forever greatful.

Is the wireless card that I bought any good? (Link above).  It had good reviews.

Comment: Is it running on the same Wi-Fi Band as your Laptop?  That is one thing to try.  Is your router capable of the Band this card is running on?

Comment: Define "exact same spot". If your laptop was on top of your desk, but your desktop tower case was under your desk, that's not the exact same spot. If your antennas are squeezed between your case and your desk or the wall behind your desk, that's a terrible place for antennas. Desktop PCIe Wi-Fi cards should always come with 1-2m of antenna cable so you can position your antennas up and away from your PC, not attach them directly to the back of your PC where they'll be so close to shielding and system RF noise.

Comment: John - They both connect on 5 ghz network band,

Comment: Spiff - i placed the laptop on the floor next to the desktop.  I have 2 antennas, that have approx 15cm gap to the wall, they were angled in a V shape. I moved the pc around and re-ran the test.  I got a speed of 0.01mbps.  I have pushed the pc back to it's original spot and now the speed is 34mbps.   So maybe it;s something to do with the positioning.  Thanks

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://beebom.com/best-ways-fix-slow-wifi-speeds/

Comment: Thanks to Spiff's recommendation I now have speeds up to 55mbps, faster than I ever had before.  So if anyone else has this issue.  Look at your wifi card antenna's.  It's kind of obvious really, but I never thought about it.  Mine never came with antenna extension cables and I never knew they existed, but after a few searches, I invested in an antenna extension, which has completely resolved my issues.  Thanks again!! Not sure how i can mark his suggestion as an answer? :\